# Google Docs download en masse

Tags: google-docs

These days I keep most of my development notes and documentations in Google Docs.  There are time that I'd like to download everything.  How is this possible on a Mac and Linux computers, without doing each one individually?  Google used to have the ability to download all spreadsheets.  However, I can no longer find this functionality.

I would like to have the documents in Open Office or HTML format.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you install google gears into your browser: http://gears.google.com/

You can use the built-in offline functionality inside of google docs

If you really want to roll up your sleeves, use the gdata API

http://code.google.com/p/gdatacopier/

Comment: The gdatacopier project is what I was looking for.  The Python API for Google is nice.  I might have to given in and use Python.

Comment: Google gears support has been dropped. There's a new HTML5 implementation of offline that allows read-only access (for now) to docs offline.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into Joe's answer.  gdatacopier is a useful tool to bulk download documents.  Here's one example that I use to download all my spreadsheets from a named folder.

```
gdoc-cp.py -e csv -g spreadsheets -o /tmp -u me@gmail.com -p password -f "MyFolder"
```

There are several examples in the documentation.  One limitation is that it does not seem to work for hosted domains.  All email addresses must be foo@gmail.com.

Bulk uploads seem quite doable too.  Getting this example to work was straight forward.

http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Create_Automated_Backups_in_Google_Docs_Using_the_GData_API

Comment: url fails now, another reference ??

Answer (score 0):

GDocBackup   http://gs.fhtino.it/gdocbackup
C#, Open Source, runs on Win + Net and Linux + Mono (not tested on Mac + Mono, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive). I have a [blog post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html) featuring a short Python script that exports a Google Sheet as CSV. You can take that example, and make these changes to make it work for you:

1. **Source** MIMEtype goes from Sheets to Docs -- for all G Suite/Google Apps (*import*) MIMEtypes, see [this page](http://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types)
2. **Destination** MIMEtype changes from CSV to *whatever you want that's supported* (Open Office & HTML included) -- for all *export* MIMEtypes, see [this page](http://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents)

If you prefer to use something other than Python, use that example as pseudocode, then create your solution in any language supported by the [Google APIs Client Libraries](http://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries). Sample code in other languages can also be found on [this page](http://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads).

Once you're done, stick it in some cron job to run it regularly without you having to think about it -- you may have to add timestamping to the exported filenames to prevent overwrites. Hope this helps!